# Do people "make parties" in New York?

Tags: phrase-usage, dialects, dialectal

> They made a party for you.

Sounds plain wrong to my ears. People don't "make a party" unless their intended meaning is that they attend it, much as "I made the train this morning." However, I lighted upon some very curious things on Google Books:

> "We came to Albany to be with my father. He **made a party for us**."
>   "A party?"
>   "A St. Patrick's Day party. He's out getting us a green cake." (source: *The Main* by [Trevanian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trevanian))

---

> Miss Crumm **made a party for the entire school**, and took us down to Norman's Falls and creek, about a half mile back into the woods, for a picnic. (source: *Jew Boy in Goy Town*)

Trevanian grew up in New York. *Jew Boy in Goy Town*, a story set in the Catskills New York, was also by an author seemingly from NY. I also found a post on [WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/make-do-give-a-party.17993/) where a user who claims to be from NY asserts that "make a party for my parents" is just as fine a usage as "throw or give a party" and another user states they've only heard it in New York and Toronto, contradicting everyone else.

So I wonder if this is a regional/dialectal usage peculiar to the New York area.

Comment: I can *conceive* of someone "making" a party, but I've really never heard it said. Had, hosted, *threw* a party—all those are perfectly idiomatic, but *making* a party? It would sound odd to me even if my best friend said it. I would assume there was some stab at humor going on, or else I didn't have all the information.

Comment: @Robusto I feel the same, but attestations of "make a party"exist. I added a link to the WordReference post, just so people know I am not blowing smoke up their patootie.

Comment: I lived in New York (Manhattan) in the 1960s and heard this expression from Jewish friends, possibly others. Never heard it elsewhere.

Comment: @Xanne: I don't doubt you. Still, I have plenty of Jewish friends in Boston and Chicago, and a few from New York, from whom I can't recall ever hearing the term. Maybe it's a dated usage as well as a localized one? (Or maybe I just didn't get invited to the right parties? ;-)

Comment: In my experience it was localized, and it could be dated, too. But I doubt it. I think it’s part of Jewish culture.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by the question itself and the comments, this seems to at least be a Jewish expression.

In the following, I've put the phrase, and other *make a* phrases, in bold:

From ["Before the Jewish Wedding"](http://www.jewishweddingtraditions.org/before-the-jewish-wedding) (undated) at Jewish Wedding Traditions:

> After the groom recites the final blessings, Sephardic communities throw candy and raisins to wish the groom a sweet life. Those who try to avoid Yiddish call this the "Shabbat Chatan", Sabbath of the Groom. Note that usually there is a simultaneous "Shabbat Kallah", where the brides' friends **make a party** for her.

From ["Crowns And Quarantines: From Purim to Pesach 5780"](https://www.jewishpress.com/sections/features/crowns-and-quarantines-from-purim-to-pesach-5780/2020/03/27/) (2020) by Yaffa Ganz at The Jewish Press:

> Inside of two weeks, public gatherings (indoors) in Israel were reduced from 5000 people to 1000 to 100 to 10. TEN? Did you ever **make a party**, or a bar mitzvah, or a *wedding* for ten people? Halls and hotels closed down in mass and thousands of weddings were held in abeyance. But you can’t keep *Am Yisrael* down.

From a reply to a post called ["Are Birthday Celebrations Un-Jewish"](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/reply/859696) (2012) at The Yeshiva World:

> I heard from my rabbeim that the idea is you are celebrating and thanking Hashem for the fact that you made it until the next year, or until you needed a new suit, etc., and they said ?? ??? one should celebrate a birthday for the same reason, even if there’s no mitzvah to **make a bracha**. Now maybe there’s no special inyan to **make a party**, but to say that it’s somehow not a Jewish idea to celebrate a birthday, is a shtus. In my humble opinion of course.

From ["The Shalom Zachor"](https://www.jewishmag.com/108mag/shalomzachor/shalomzachor.htm) (2006) by Larry Fine at Jewish Magazine:

> We all know that when a boy is born a brit is in the makings. However what is lesser known is the tradition of the *Shalom Zachor*. This very special custom follows the birth of a boy: the Ashkenazic Jews **make a party** on the first Friday night following the birth of a boy and this is called the "*Shalom Zachor*", whereas the Sephardic Jews **make a "*Brit Yitzhak*"** on the evening preceding the brit.

---

Looking at these contexts, it could be that *party*, in all of these uses, is more synonymous with *group* than *celebration*. That would especially make sense if it's related to religious functions. But note that even in English, a *wedding party* is more of a *wedding group* than a *wedding celebration*.

---

Not being part of this culture, I can't claim any kind of personal knowledge of it. But these sources all point to a related use of the phrase.

As for the reference in the question itself, although the Wikipedia entry on Trevanian doesn't mention his exposure to Jewish culture, it's not unreasonable that didn't happen. It's also pretty clear that *Jew Boy in Goy Town* (set in New York), is influenced by Jewish culture.

If also possible it's mainly only related to Jewish culture in New York specifically. (But also in Toronto, in one report.) Or perhaps it has a more observed religious context rather than something general.

Comment: Are there dates for your references? I'm curious whether this is a dated expression.

Comment: @Robusto I have updated my answer to include the dates for each entry. One is undated, and the others range from 2006 to 2020.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was merely unobservant or else firmly in the Goy Zone.